# Connection refuse on post request

Tags: docker, apache, http, request

I have to update a repo
So, I created an image from python:3.7:slim

I am using flask for the application
After building the image I tries to send a post requst but I got

```
rllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.14.2.96', port=8085): Max retries exceeded with url: /run_product_clustering_request/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f344c13b5f8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Here is the docker file

```
FROM python:3.7-slim
MAINTAINER XXX

WORKDIR /srv/src/product_clustering

WORKDIR /srv/src
ADD . ./product_clustering
RUN mkdir /var/log/product_clustering
ENV LOG_PATH=/var/log/product_clustering
ENV NLTK_DATA=/srv/data/research/product_clustering/data/nltk_data

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apache2 apache2-utils && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


WORKDIR /srv/src/product_clustering
RUN pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt -i https://XXX/pypi-all/simple/ --trusted-host XXX.co
RUN chmod 777 -R /var/log/product_clustering



#RUN chmod 777 -R /var/www

#RUN pip3 install --upgrade scipy -i XXX.co/repository/pypi-all/simple/ --trusted-host XXX

WORKDIR /srv/src
ADD ./clustering.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/
ADD ./clustering.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
#RUN rm /etc/apache2/sites-available/scraping-bk.conf
ENV PYTHONPATH=/srv/src/product_clustering/

RUN chown www-data: /srv/src
RUN chmod u+w /srv/src

# Expose Apache2 ports
EXPOSE 80 443
```

**Edit**
I ran the image locally and I got this error:

```
Apache Configuration Error AH00558: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name
```

Here is the conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin <XXX>
   ServerName product_clustering
   DocumentRoot  /srv/src/product_clustering/

   ErrorLog /var/log/product_clustering/error.log
   ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/1
   ErrorLogFormat "%M"

   WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
   WSGIProcessGroup product_clustering
   WSGIDaemonProcess product_clustering processes=1 threads=100 python-path=/srv/src/product_clustering/ inactivity-timeout=18000 deadlock-timeout=18000
   WSGIScriptAlias / /srv/src/product_clustering/run.wsgi process-group=product_clustering application-group=%{GLOBAL}
   WSGIPassAuthorization On
</VirtualHost>

<Directory  /srv/src/product_clustering/>
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: I can't see any entrypoint in your Dockerfile. What is your container supposed to run?

Comment: The jenkins probably do that

Comment: this is not enough information. What code/command is failing (where does this error come from)? How is the container run? Are the exposed ports actually mapped to host ports when running the container?

Comment: @StefanR
I created an image and run it locally and I have the same problem.

Comment: sending request with - requests.post('http://localhost:3000/run_product_clustering_request/', json=body)

Comment: If you got a 'connection refused' the TCP connection failed. This happened before HTTP started. so it is unrelated to POST. You need to focus on the network side.

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri I updated the details

Comment: How did you run the container? Is the HTTP request you are running from within the container, from within another container or from the host system?